# Sketch the graph of $\sinh^{-1}(\cosh x)$

Tags: graphing-functions, hyperbolic-functions

Sketch the graph of the function $f(x) = \sinh^{-1}(\cosh x)$.

I am asking whether there is an algebraic method of answering the question. Or should I just create a subset of points and substitute directly?

Thank you!

Comment: There's not much simplification that could be made here. It should be sufficient for a sketch to prove that $f$ is even, strictly increasing for $x\gt0$ and that $f(x)\sim x$ for $x\to\infty$.

Comment: To add to Peter's comments, $f(x) > x$ for $x \geq 0$, and $f(x) - x$ is maximal for $x = 0$.